# 'Match' on OrientDB returns a path that doesn't exist

Tags: orientdb

I am using OrientDB 'match' to get a path (on the graph) according to a criteria, but I get a result path that doesn't exist.

I have a "Person" vertex that has a "PhoneCall" edge to another "Person" vertex - only one path should be a match!
so I expext to get as a result: vertex1-edgeX-vertex2
For example - "jonn Smith --phoneCallX-- dan smith"

What I actually get is 2 pathes:

1. vertex1-edgeX-vertex2 (jonn Smith --phoneCallX-- dan smith) but also:
2. vertex1-edgeX-vertex**1** - it is not true since it is the same edge-@rid from the first result and also it is NOT a self edge: jonn Smith --phoneCallX-- jonn Smith

The query:

```
MATCH {class:person, as:E1, where:( (   firstName IN ['John']   ) )}.bothE(){class:phoneCall, as:R0}.bothV(){class:person, as:E0, where:( (   lastName IN ['Smith']   ) )} RETURN $paths
```

I think it is happening because of the "both()" method **with** the fact that the first vertex apply to both filters:

1. firstName IN ['John']
2. List item lastName IN ['Smith']

But still - I meant to find all paths of "John-phoneCall-Smith" and I got an edge (that doesn't exist) between this John to himself just because his name is Smith (which should be the condition of the OTHER entity of this relation) )

Please help me - what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly specify that the two vertices have to be different.
The syntax is, in the WHERE condition of E2, `$matched.E1 <> $currentMatch`

```
MATCH 
   {class:person, as:E1, where:( (   firstName IN ['John']   ) )}
      .bothE(){class:phoneCall, as:R0}
      .bothV(){class:person, as:E0, where:(lastName IN ['Smith'] AND $matched.E1 <> $currentMatch)} 
RETURN $paths
```

Comment: Thanks! really helped. (but I support a self edges as well so I had to use your solution condition only when it is not a case of a self edge.)

anyway - is there a name/title to the "system variables" such as '$matched' and '$currentMatch'? I want to view the whole list

Comment: Sure, here is a list https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Match.html#context-variables (pretty short, actually)